# mozilla's bind function question

Tags: javascript

Had a question about a implementation of bind function that I found on Mozilla's site.  For the most part it makes sense to me, but I cant figure out what this check is for...

```
this instanceof nop ? this : ( obj || {} )
```

in the bind function.  Obviously its checking if 'this' is the empty function, but why would you need to bind the empty function.  I have tried it in firebug, it works, but what is the point?  Just trying to increase my javascript knowledge so any help would be appreciated.

```
if ( !Function.prototype.bind ) {

  Function.prototype.bind = function( obj ) {

    var slice = [].slice,
    args = slice.call(arguments, 1), 
    self = this, 
    nop = function () {}, 
    bound = function () {
      return self.apply( this instanceof nop ? this : ( obj || {} ), 
                          args.concat( slice.call(arguments) ) );    
    };

    nop.prototype = self.prototype;

    bound.prototype = new nop();

    return bound;
  };
}
```

Comment: Pop up the js console and evaluate it, see what you get!

Comment: This is really confusing .. Since it's calling itself it might use it to prevent an infinite loop? Or it might just be for performance?

Comment: yeah - i did try it - it works but I'm bound to the empty function so nothing really happens.  Was just wondering if anyone had any insight as to why I would do this, or why it was written like this

Comment: Also, why is it splitting up the arguments, only to concat them again later on? Is that fast? I would guess arguments.concat([]) is the fastest way to clone.

Comment: the arguments are split the first time because if you did something like this --- function.bind obj arg1 arg2  - you would get back a function that is bound to an object that has arg1 and arg2 filled in - a partial application of the function --- then when you call the actual bound function with args, those are concatenating with the args you original bound the function with --- at least thats the best i can do to explain

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Its allows you to call the bound function as a constructor without being bound to the original object. In other words the "bound" function will still work just like the original, unbound version if you call it with `new`.

Here's an example:

```
var obj = {};

function foo(x) {
    this.answer = x;
}
var bar = foo.bind(obj);   // "always" use obj for "this"

bar(42);
console.log(obj.answer);   // 42

var other = new bar(1);    // Call bar as a constructor
console.log(obj.answer);   // Still 42
console.log(other.answer); // 1
```

### How it works

To simplify the explanation, here's a simplified version of the code that only binds `this` and doesn't handle arguments or a missing obj parameter:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function( obj ) {
  var self = this,
  nop = function () {},
  bound = function () {
    return self.apply( this instanceof nop ? this : obj, arguments );
  };

  nop.prototype = self.prototype;
  bound.prototype = new nop();

  return bound;
};
```

The function that gets returned by `Function.prototype.bind` behaves differently depending on whether you use it as a function, or a constructor (see [Section 15.3.4.5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5.1) and [15.3.4.5.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5.2) of the ECMAScript 5 Language Specification). The primary difference, is that it ignores the "bound this" parameter when it's called as a constructor (since inside a constructor, `this` needs to be the newly-created object). So the `bound` function needs a way to determine how it's being called. For example, `bound(123)` vs. `new bound(123)` and set `this` accordingly.

That's where the `nop` function comes in. It's essentially acting as an intermediate "class" so that `bound` extends `nop` which extends `self` (which is the function `bind()` was called on). That part is set up here:

```
nop.prototype = self.prototype;
bound.prototype = new nop();
```

When you call the bound function, it returns this expression:

```
self.apply( this instanceof nop ? this : obj, arguments ) )
```

`this instanceof nop` works by following the prototype chain to determine the if any prototype of `this` is equal to `nop.prototype`. By setting `nop.prototype = self.prototype` and `bound.prototype = new nop()`, any object created with `new bound()` will be created with the original prototype from `self` via `bound.prototype`. So inside the function call, `this instanceof nop` (i.e. Object.getPrototypeOf(nop) == nop.prototype) is `true` and `self` gets called with `this` (the newly created object).

In a normal function call, 'bound()' (without `new`), `this instanceof nop` would be false, so `obj` gets passed as the `this` context, which is what you would expect on a bound function.

The reason for using the intermediate function is to avoid calling the original function (in the line `bound.prototype = new nop();`), which may have side effects.

Comment: very interesting and looks correct - i would have never thought of that - thank you

Comment: Somehow, I do not understand how the `nop` above is affecting this answer.

Comment: @SunnyRGupta I guess I answered *what* it does, but didn't explain how it actually works. It gets pretty deep into how javascript works, but I'll see if I can explain it.

Comment: @SunnyRGupta I don't remember if SO would have notified you when the answer was edited, but I added some explanation for how the nop() function works. Hopefully it makes a little bit of sense at least.

Comment: `this instanceof nop (i.e. Object.getPrototypeOf(nop) == nop.prototype)` did not quite understand, do you mean `Object.getPrototypeOf(this) == nop.prototype` ?

Comment: And why not use `bound.prototype = new self()` directly ? Thanks in advance ~

Comment: @TinaChen The `bind` function can't call `new self()` because that calls the function, which could have side effects. For example, if you had this function: `function f() { alert('oops'); }`, it would be surprising (and incorrect) for `f.bind({})` to show an alert. The `nop` function is defined inside `bind`, and doesn't do anything, so it's safe to call.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe i'm totally wrong but:

Why don't use only the prototype of the first function that call bind to use as condition, insteadof create a new function like nop()?, it works for me.

Maybe it's important to create the nop() function for some reason, that i don't undrestand yet.(i'm new in JavaScript)

```
Function.prototype.bind = function( obj ) {

var slice = [].slice,
args = slice.call(arguments, 1), 
self = this,  
bound = function () {
  return self.apply( this instanceof self ? this : ( obj || {} ), 
                      args.concat( slice.call(arguments) ) );    
};

bound.prototype = self.prototype;

return bound;
};
```

Comment: `bound.prototype = self.prototype` **does not mean**, that `bound instanceof self == true`. So check `this instanceof self ?` wouldn't work.  On the other hand, `bound.prototype = new self ()` **does mean**, that  `bound instanceof self == true`. (it may be easily checked in browser console). But callin self() may bring side effect, as it was mentioned by @MatthewCrumley. So you need fresh new **empty** function to call with new

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a short notation for `(typeof obj != "undefined") ? obj : {}`

That is, if `obj` is not undefined, return `obj`, else, return an empty object ({} is an empty object).

Comment: hmm - not sure if I just don't completely understand your answer because I am certainly not a javascript expert but the part that is giving me pause is the "this instance of nop ? this"  which seems to say if "this" is the empty function then return "this" - which means we are binding the empty function

Comment: The ( obj || {} )  part is pretty clear. It's the 'nop' part that is confusing.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I did a quick read and I missed the point, let me read it again :)