# Why does the bind polyfill on MDN introduce an intermediary NOP function instance onto the prototype property?

Tags: javascript, bind

I note that the [polyfill at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill) introduces an intermediary NOP function instance onto the prototype property of the returned function. Why?

From MDN:

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
  Function.prototype.bind = function(oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== 'function') {
      // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5
      // internal IsCallable function
      throw new TypeError('Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable');
    }

    var aArgs   = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
        fToBind = this,
        fNOP    = function() {},
        fBound  = function() {
          return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP && oThis
                 ? this
                 : oThis,
                 aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
        };

    fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    return fBound;
  };
}
```

---

My current implementation without modifying the prototype property:

```
function myBind(receiver) {
  var functionToBind,
      argsArray, 
      functionToReturn;

  if(typeof this !== 'function') {
    throw 'myBind must be called on a function.';
  }

  functionToBind = this; // For use in different execution contexts.
  argsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1); // Slice off the supplied receiver.

  functionToReturn = function() {
    var concatenatedArgs,
         newArgsArray;

    newArgsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    concatenatedArgs = argsArray.concat(newArgsArray);

    return functionToBind.apply(receiver, concatenatedArgs);
  };

  functionToReturn.prototype = this.prototype;

  return functionToReturn;
}

function foo(a,b,c) {
  console.log(a,b,c);
  this.bar = function() { console.log('bar'); }
}

var bound = myBind.call(foo, window, 'a');
bound('b'); // 'a b undefined'
window.bar(); // 'bar'

var bound2 = myBind.call(bound, window, 'b');
bound2(); // 'a b undefined'
```

**EDIT: I have reworded the question so as to fall within SO question guidelines.**

Comment: Note that [passing the `arguments` object out of a function probably disqualifies the function from being optimized.](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers)

Comment: I have significantly re-worded this question so it should be answerable now.

Comment: I think this might be helpful too:  [MDN Function.prototype.bind bound function called as constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23693282/mdn-function-prototype-bind-bound-function-called-as-constructor)

Comment: The problem with your implementation is that functions made with your implementation don't work correctly when used as a constructor: http://jsfiddle.net/0mrrb2vz/2/

Comment: @JLRishe thanks that is exactly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: This question addresses the issue too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376062/reason-behind-using-instanceof-function?lq=1