# what is "this instanceof fNOP ? this" doing?

Tags: javascript

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
    Function.prototype.bind = function (oThis) {
        if (typeof this !== "function") {
            // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5 internal IsCallable function  
            throw new TypeError("Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable");
        }

        var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
            fToBind = this,
            fNOP = function () {},
            fBound = function () {
                return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP ? this : oThis || window, aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
            };

        fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
        fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

        return fBound;
    };
}
```

this is pick from [bind MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind),i don't understand what is `this instanceof fNOP ? this` doing. would someone to teach me,please? i want to know why not use `oThis || window` directly.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? What [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) is doing? Or the [conditional operator `cond ? true : false`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)? Both are covered in the MDN documentation. If you ask for the *reason* why this construct is used, it is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774070/mozillas-bind-function-question).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question mark in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771786/question-mark-in-javascript)

Comment: i understand both.but i want to know why not use `oThis || window` directly.

Comment: Well, `this` is different from `oThis` and `window`, so you would change the functionality. It seems you are probably more interested in the question I linked to already: [mozilla's bind function question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774070/mozillas-bind-function-question).

Comment: dont understand
`
 fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
        fBound.prototype = new fNOP();
`

Answer (score 1):

```
return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP ? this : oThis || window, aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
```

if `this` is an instance of `fNOP`, the first argument will be `this`. if not, then it will be `oThis` if it's "truthy" (not null, not undefined and anything synonymous to false), or `window` of `oThis` is false.

its a shorthand to this code:

```
if(this instanceof fNOP){
    firstparameter = this;
} else {
    if(oThis){
        firstParameter = oThis;
    } else {
        firstParameter = window;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why no just check `this insatnceof fBound` here?