# Unable to understand prototype in bind polyfill

Tags: javascript, bind, prototypejs, polyfills, prototype-chain

I read through polyfill of bind function from MDN.
I am unable to understand why **fBound.prototype = new fNOP();** is written in code??
I got an link but not able to understand what author is trying to convey([mozilla's bind function question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774070/mozillas-bind-function-question))

Here is code :

```js
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
  Function.prototype.bind = function(oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== 'function') {
      // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5
      // internal IsCallable function
      throw new TypeError('Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable');
    }

    var aArgs   = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
        fToBind = this,
        fNOP    = function() {},
        fBound  = function() {
          return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP
                 ? this
                 : oThis,
                 aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
        };

    if (this.prototype) {
      // Function.prototype doesn't have a prototype property
      fNOP.prototype = this.prototype; 
    }
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    return fBound;
  };
}
```

Comment: which part don't you understand?

Comment: why fBound.prototype = new fNOP(); is written in code?

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5774147/5238583) has well explained your question, so I advise to mark this question as the duplicate, or you can add comments to that answer.

In short, `fBound.prototype = new fNOP()` is used to solve the precedence of `this`, which is:

`new` binding > explicit binding (`call`, `apply`, `bind`) > implicit binding (`var bar = obj1.foo()`) > default binding(`undefined`/`global` object)

More details and reasons behind this : [determining this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1026e4d56521890a13e73e08f5ffa1b9c70039c8/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md#determining-this)

`fBound.prototype = new fNOP()` is used in `this instanceof fNOP ? this : oThis`

if `this instanceof fNOP` returns `true`, it means `this` is the `new` create object and `fBound` is called as a constructor: `new fBound()`, so discard `oThis`, use `this`. (`new` binding)

If `this instanceof fNOP` returns `false`, it means `fBound` is called as a normal function, so use `oThis` passed in `bind`. (explicit binding)